# Auto Calculation returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Qnt, Unit Price and Total Price input fields. Also I've written a jQuery code for auto calculation.

Html -

```
<input class="form-control qnt" min="0" step="any" type="number" name="qnt" placeholder="Quantity" required>
<input class="form-control unit_price" type="number" min="0" step="any" name="unit_price" placeholder="Unit Price" required>
<input class="form-control total_price" type="number" name="total_price" placeholder="Total Price" value="" readonly>
```

JQuery -

```
$('table.table').change('input', function () {
    var Qnt = $('.qnt').val();
    var UnitPrice = $('.unit_price').val();
    var totalPrice = parseInt(Qnt) * parseInt(UnitPrice);
    $('.total_price').val(totalPrice); // Result Print
});
```

This code calculates fine, but the problem is, if I try to catch **Total Price** value (`$('.total_price').val();`) it returns **Undefined**. After I **console** the `totalPrice` first time it return **null null** then result.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Thanks In advance.

Note: My table fields created automatically using Ajax. sorry I did not intimation that earlier.

Comment: Assuming you have more than one element associated with the class `total_price`, what would you expect from that code?

Answer (score 3):

You should change your target to input rather than a class, like below, and when change event on first input fires, that will give NaN output, as other input would be empty at that time, a simple check of NaN (not a number) should be enough, and you should not rely on a bootstrap class, because, in case in future you move onto some other frame, you would need to change the class name, and the script will stop working, so, either target input tag directly, or add your own custom class for targeting

```
$('.form-control').change('input', function() {
  var Qnt = $('.qnt').val(),
  UnitPrice = $('.unit_price').val(),
  totalPrice = parseInt(Qnt) * parseInt(UnitPrice);
  (!isNaN(totalPrice)) ?  $('.total_price').empty().val(totalPrice): '';
});
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8tnr1uqx/1/) of it

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simple trick. Validate the inputs if it has a value, if not it will be considered as zero(0). In this example we add an IF statement to validate the second input.

```
$('.form-control').on('change', function(){
        var qnt = $('.qnt').val();   
        var unit_price = $('.unit_price').val();    
        if(unit_price > 0){
            unit_price = unit_price;
           }else {
               unit_price = 0;
           }
        var total = parseInt(qnt) * parseInt(unit_price);
        $('.total_price').empty().val(total);

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change function selector was wrong .its a `.from-control` and empty total price before add with in

```js
$('.form-control').change('input', function() {
  var Qnt = $('.qnt').val();
  var UnitPrice = $('.unit_price').val();
  var totalPrice = parseInt(Qnt) * parseInt(UnitPrice);
  $('.total_price').empty().val(totalPrice); // Result Print
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control qnt" min="0" step="any" type="number" name="qnt" placeholder="Quantity" required>
<input class="form-control unit_price" type="number" min="0" step="any" name="unit_price" placeholder="Unit Price" required>
<input class="form-control total_price" type="number" name="total_price" placeholder="Total Price" value="" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for help. I've solved my problem. I just create auto custom ID's for individual table rows and it works perfectly.

```js
$('#cus1').change('input', function () {
     var Qnt = $('.qnt').val();
     var UnitPrice = $('.unit_price').val();
     var totalPrice = parseInt(Qnt) * parseInt(UnitPrice);
     $('.total_price').val(totalPrice); // Result Print
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cus1">
<input class="form-control qnt" min="0" step="any" type="number" name="qnt" placeholder="Quantity" required>
<input class="form-control unit_price" type="number" min="0" step="any" name="unit_price" placeholder="Unit Price" required>
<input class="form-control total_price" type="number" name="total_price" placeholder="Total Price" value="" readonly>
</div>
```